# WP Metaboxes Multi Select update, get current

Tags: php, wordpress, post, metadata

The last thing that is currently not working in my plugin is the multi select input field. It is shown, items can be selected, but updating the post 1) does not save selected values and 2) does not load them when entering the edit screen.

My code:

```
<?php
// METABOX I Diet Information

function diet_add_meta_box1() {
    add_meta_box( 'diet_meta_box1', __( 'Diet Information', 'nutriplus' ), 'diet_build_meta_box1', "np-diet", "side", "high", null);
    }
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'diet_add_meta_box1' );

/**
 * Build custom field METABOX I
 *
 * @param post $post The post object
 */

function diet_build_meta_box1( $post ){
    // make sure the form request comes from WordPress
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'diet_meta_box1_nonce' );

    // retrieve the current values

$current_diet_goals = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_diet_diet_goals', false );
?>
<div>
    <label for="diet-goals" class="np-label"><strong><?php _e( 'Diet Goals', 'nutriplus' ) ?></strong></label>
    <p>
    <select name="diet_goals[]" id="np-dropdown" class="np-dropdown" multiple>
        <option value="build-body" <?php selected( in_array( 'build-body', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Build Body', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="build-muscle" <?php selected( in_array( 'build-muscle', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Build Muscle', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="eat-healthy" <?php selected( in_array( 'eat-healthy', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Eat Healthy', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="gain-weight" <?php selected( in_array( 'gain-weight', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Gain Weight', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="hold-weight" <?php selected( in_array( 'hold-weight', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Hold Weight', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="improve-condition" <?php selected( in_array( 'improve-condition', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Improve Condition', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="improve-performance" <?php selected( in_array( 'improve-performance', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Improve Performance', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="lose-fat" <?php selected( in_array( 'lose-fat', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Lose Fat', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
        <option value="lose-weight" <?php selected( in_array( 'lose-weight', $current_diet_goals, true ) ); ?>><?php _e( 'Lose Weight', 'nutriplus' ) ?></option>
    </select>
    </p>
    </div>
<?php
}
function diet_save_meta_box1_data( $post_id ){
    // verify meta box nonce
    if ( !isset( $_POST['diet_meta_box1_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['diet_meta_box1_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ){
        return;
    }
    // return if autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }
  // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ){
        return;
    }   
    // store custom fields values METABOX1
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['diet_goals'] ) ) {
        $array = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', wp_unslash( $_POST['diet_goals'] ) );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_diet_diet_goals',  $array );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'diet_save_meta_box1_data' );
?>
```

I have an idea of what can be wrong.
Maybe this part:

```
$current_diet_goals = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_diet_diet_goals', false );
```

Obviously the save_meta function and I think the field name too.
I searched a lot to the internet to solve this, but I did not succeed in mirroring the solutions I found on my code :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need change your attribute name in select.

Use `diet_goals[]` instead `diet_goals`

and change your are selected functions on:

```
selected( in_array( 'some-value', $current_diet_goals, true ) );
```

Comment: I changed it to diet_goals[], but obviously there is more. Still no saving of the selected choices

Comment: Updated my first post to current version. Still not saving.